Good approximation of $\sin(x)^5$ to use for ODE?
I need to find an approximate solution of $x'(t)= - \sin(x)^5$ with $x \in [0, \pi]$. I know there's no explicit solution, but I wonder if there are good approximations (whatever that means, let's say in the sup norm) of $\sin(x)^5$ with some function $f (x)$ such that the ODE $x'(t)= f(x)$ is solvable with an explicit formula (even very long and ugly, I'll put the ODE in Mathematica to see what is spit out anyway).

There may be an explicit solution $t=t(x)$ if you take reciprocals, thus $dt/dx=\csc^5(x)$ which can be integrated (use IBP). You get $t$ in terms of $x$ and should not expect to be able to solve for $x$ in terms of $t$.

For this function, you can divide by $sin^5(x)$, and integration gives https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+1+%2F+sin%5E5+x . As mentioned above, you'll express $t$ in terms of $x$, and you can probably find $x$ in terms of $t$ numerically very efficiently.

If you really have just the one function (and not a family of functions that looks like that), why not solve it to whatever precision you need numerically, and then fit a polynomial or other approximating function to the result?

$\LARGE W &  \alpha$ Result.

You should maybe also tell us why you are interested in the ODE and what you need from it. Then we can maybe help more effectively...

Why not use a Taylor polynomial for sine?

Thanks everyone! This ODE comes from a physics problem and it describes the motion of a particle. I need to calculate the position of a particle starting in a certain position after a time $t$ for many cases (the starting points are the entries of a matrix of size $N \times N$) and I do not know if the method proposed by Dmitry and Lenzi can work (I guess to invert one would use Newton's method or something similar, maybe it's not viable to do that $N^2$ times?). Approximating via a polynomial is possible, but it will depend on the time interval chosen. A nice closed formula would be better.
